# QtWebkit as a desktop application GUI

Tags: c++, windows, qt, webkit

I was wondering if anyone knows about good tutorials or articles describing methods of creating an HTML GUI for an application using QTWebKit for a windows desktop application.

I am mainly concerned about communicating messages, events and information between lets say a DLL(written in C++ for example) and the GUI (QtWebKit).

need good reliable references...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't be easy: Web browsers are fortresses because of security concerns. So it's pretty hard to get from JS in a web page to something outside of the browser.

<s>Also, QtWebKit isn't a very open API. The biggest obstacle in your case is that it doesn't offer you access to the DOM, so you can only replace the whole HTML.</s>

Therefore, you'll need to patch and write a lot of code to implement the missing APIs and functions.

Since Qt 4.6 has been released, there is QWebElement ([see the docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt4-6-intro.html#dom-access-api) for examples), so you can at least access the DOM and modify it. That will make a lot of things more simple. I suggest to decide who controls the browser: Will your app be JavaScript which calls outside or is the app really in C++ and you use the browser as a smart UI renderer?

A much more simple way might be to make your idea work would be to start an internal web server when your app starts and then open a QtWebKit view pointing to the URL of the local server. Then, you could use all the standard web development tools. Eclipse uses this technique for its internal help system.

Comment: doeesn't QWebElement and QWebElementSelection give access to manipulating DOM elements??

Comment: I wasn't aware that Qt 4.6 has already been release. You're right, see this link: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt4-6-intro.html#dom-access-api

Comment: I've improved my answer.

Comment: Its the latter case "app really in C++ and you use the browser as a smart UI renderer"

Comment: Aaron, mapping script calls to C++ and event handling is in my opinion complicated by routing it through an additional layer (i.e. the webserver). Also, implementing custom drawn elements (video, ...) gets quite hackish.

Answer (score 3):

I'm copy/pasting bits from different sections but this is how I insert an object that is available to javascript, then I use javascript to talk to the main app. Seems to work well...

```
void MyApi::setWebView( QWebView *view ) {

    QWebPage *page = view->page();
    m_frame = page->mainFrame();

    attachObject();
    connect( m_frame, SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()), 
        this, SLOT(attachObject()) );

}

void MyApi::attachObject() {

    m_frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject( QString("MyApi"), this );

}
```

This makes a `MyApi` object exist in javascript and I can call any slots made available from the `MyApi` class.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/04/07/qwebelement-sees-the-light-do-i-hear-a-booyakasha/

http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/04/17/jquery-and-qwebelement/

Comment: I was just looking into the first link just now, and maybe thats the solution.... I think I'll have to study the classes well first before moving on just to see if these are the ultimate solution.

Still not sure about the communication bit from the DLL to the page...

Answer (score 2):

For the basic usage, the [examples](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/examples-webkit.html) from trolltech should get you started.

The plus-side of the Qt approach is that exposing objects to the script is relatively easy, see e.g. [here](http://www.kdedevelopers.org/node/4008). JavaScript in the different embedded webkits can then easily communicate with C++ (and of course with script in other windows if you provide support on the C++ side for that). The down-side is that the API doesn't seem to be quite stable yet and seems to be missing support for adding event listeners from JavaScript to C++ objects (or at least i didn't see how it was supposed to be done).

Placing custom drawn elements into the page is again quite simplified, you embed plugins into the page (e.g. via the `<object>` tag) and return custom QWidgets from [QWebPluginFactory::create()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwebpluginfactory.html#create).

On important thing to always keep in mind: calls to the embedded webkit (e.g. for evaluating JavaScript) should always occur on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for an insightful comment. Can you provide any more information on why "calls to the embedded webkit (e.g. for evaluating JavaScript) should always occur on the main thread"?

Comment: In any current browser i know of the script engine resides in the main thread and is not thread-safe. The plugin-developer has to make sure that the calls into the browser are issued from the right thread unless some API functions already take care of that - if you don't you get undefined behaviour and most likely crashes.